# jQuery UI: Get the droppable index which the draggable is in on DRAG

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm making a jigsaw puzzle in HTML. 
There's a table which has empty spaces and below the table there are pieces which fit exactly into the empty spaces.

So I know how to get the draggable and droppable element on drop and how do get the draggable element on drag. But how do I get the droppable element in which the draggable element currently resides on drag event. Also if a draggable element isn't inside a droppable element it shouldn't break the code.

http://altement.ee/overflow/ click on on a button to start the puzzle too see what I have made. I need to know in which droppable element it is in right now to know if it is in a correct spot already or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I get the droppable element in which the draggable element currently resides on drag event"? Do you want to determine the html content of the droppable section or something else?

Comment: I want a .attr of the droppable section.

Comment: All of your droppable sections are `div`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`over`**](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over)

> Triggered when an accepted draggable is dragged over the droppable

If that doesn't workout for some reason, try [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint).

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26960332/2333214) that does it.